# change signal inside a process with if statement - VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have this code in VHDL.  What I want is to rise rst when sw'event and afterwards, the rst is to fall by itself.  But when I simulate this, rst never falls!

```
process(rst,clk,sw)
    begin
        if (clk'EVENT and clk='1') then
              if (rst='1') then 
                  rst<='0';
              elsif (sw'event) then
                  rst<='1';
              elsif (my_counter="11") then
                  deb_sw<=sw;   
              end if;    
        end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Is this code also to be used in FPGA (synthesized code), or only in simulation (test bench) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i solved it like this

```
process(rst,clk,sw)
    begin
        if (clk'EVENT and clk='1') then
              if (rst='1' and rst'last_value='0') then 
                  rst<='0';
              elsif (sw='1') then 
                 rst<='1';
                 deb_sw<=sw;
              elsif (my_counter="1010") then      -- clock cycles=10*f
                  deb_sw<=sw;   
              end if;    
        end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1):

sw'event is very unlikely to be true at exactly the same time as clk'event is.

This is because signals are usually driven by another process which is also doing a clk'event, so the signal will be updated *after* the clk event.

If you want to detect when sw changes from '0' to '1' (or vice versa), you have to keep track of its previous value:

```
if sw /= last_sw then
  -- do what you need to do when it changes
end if;
last_sw := sw;
```