# What is the correct implementation of handling asynchronous signals in an FSM?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

We are implementing an Ethernet MAC controller in VHDL..

To start of, here is a code snippet of my code..

```
-- next state
PROCESS(p_state, phy_start, phy_ctr, phy_clk)
BEGIN
    CASE p_state IS
        WHEN sIDLE =>
            IF(phy_start = '1' or rising_edge(phy_start)) THEN
                n_state <= sPRE;
            ELSIF(phy_start'event AND phy_start='0') THEN
                n_state <= n_state;
            ELSE
                n_state <= sIDLE;
            END IF;
     ............
```

The problem is that my professor told me I associated phy_start as the clock signal where in the rising_edge() must be only associated to only one clock which is phy_clk. What I want to happen is when phy_start asserts, it would go to sPRE state at the next clock cycle. The assertion is done in the rising edge of the clock. I have tried

```
    PROCESS(p_state, phy_start, phy_ctr, phy_clk)
BEGIN
    CASE p_state IS
        WHEN sIDLE =>
            IF(phy_start = '1') THEN
                n_state <= sPRE;
            ELSIF(phy_start'event AND phy_start='0') THEN
                n_state <= n_state;
            ELSE
                n_state <= sIDLE;
     .............
```

but it does not enter the phy_start = '1' because it happened in the transition.. (there is what we call the setup time in which the data must be stable in that duration in order to be read correctly). What is the correct implementation then? Or I have no choice but to assert the phy_start for 2 clock cycles if the assertion happens in the rising edge, or phy_start must be asserted in the falling edge of the clock. ALso, what is the correct set of sensitivity list for the next state logic?

Answer (score 1):

If everything is clocked under `phy_clk`, you should never use rising_edge() or 'event on other signals. These are associated to the clocks, not the signals.
If you want to detect when a signal clocked on `phy_clk` rises, you should proceed like this:

```
process(phy_clk,nreset)
begin
  if nreset = '0' then
    phy_start_d <= '0';
  elsif phy_clk = '1' and phy_clk'event then
    phy_start_d <= phy_start;
  end if;
end process;
phy_start_p <= phy_start and not phy_start_d;
```

the `phy_start_p` signal is set to 1 only when `phy_start` rises, and it's totally synchronous with `phy_clk`;

Comment: What is the nreset for?

Comment: you normally need to reset the signals at the beginning, in order to start with a well known configuration. Typically the reset signal is active low, so is the inverted of a reset. For this reason I called it nreset (negate reset). Here you can simply delete it, but for other kind of design, if you don't have a reset status at beginning, you'll have some serious problems.

Comment: What would be the value of phy_start when it asserted at the rising edge of the clock as such you have designed a logic as you have provided?

Comment: As many have already said, if phy_start is supposed to be a synchronous signal, it will change at the rising edges of the phy_clk signal. You have to remember that the change on a signal is not instantaneous, even in simulations the phy_start will change some deltas afterwards...

Answer (score 0):

There has been a related question with answers recently, which you can find at:
[how many processes i need to monitor two signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20469513/2352082)

It is useful to keep in mind that VHDL is for describing hardware (design), so
the synthesis tool can convert the description to fit the available hardware,
which is typically flip flops (sequential design) and gates (combinatorial
design).  The synthesis tools does typically have some recommendations for
writing VHDL, so the translation to hardware will work smoothly.

For flip flops with asynchronous reset (rst) and rising edge clock (clk), with
next value generated by optional gates, the VHDL is typically:

```
-- Template for flip flops
process (clk, rst) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    -- Flip flops outputs updated on rising edge of clk
  end if;
  if rst = '1' then
    -- Flip flops outputs assigned with constant value when rst is '1'
  end if;
end process;
```

Only `rst` and `clk` should be in the sensitivity list, so other signals used
in expressions in the process should not be included.  Any expressions used to
generate the value for the flip flop will be converted to gates by the tool.

Only rising edge clock should be used for flip flop, unless there is a good
reason to use falling edge clock, or even both edges, since using only a single
edge will make it easier to do the timing constraining.

If asynchronous reset is not used, then leave out the `rst` from the
sensitivity list and remove the related if statement.

For pure gates the VHDL is typically, assuming use of VHDL-2008:

```
-- Template for gates
process (all) is
begin
  -- Gates outputs updated based
end process;
```

or for simple expression just drop the process and write:

```
my_signal <= my_expression;
```

So back to the specific code, then it is possible to write this as a single
process with `phy_clk` as clock:

```
PROCESS (phy_clk)
BEGIN
    IF RISING_EDGE(phy_clk) THEN
        CASE p_state IS
            WHEN sIDLE =>
                p_state <= ...  -- New value for state based on signals
```

When it is required to react on changes in signals, like `phy_start` going from
'0' to '1', then a signal with a single cycle delayed version of `phy_start`
can be made, for example `phy_start_ff`, and the an expression can be written
in the code like:

```
if (phy_start_ff = '0') and (phy_start = '1') then  -- phy_start from 0 to 1
  ..
```

Comment: Will phy_start be detected as '1' upon the rising edge of the phy_start?

Comment: The description assumes that all state changes are synchronous to a single clock, which is assumed to be `phy_clk`.  So state is not updated until rising edge of `phy_clk`, but if `phy_start` is then '1' and was '0' at previous `phy_clk` rising edge, then the change is detected.  I updated the above `PROCESS (phy_clk)` with information that `p_state` (present state) is updated.

Comment: What if the phy_start asserted at the same time as phy_clk? At that instance, phy_start has not yet reached the minimum required time setup and the signal phy_start is already read in the if condition.. Will it not read an indeterminate value?

Comment: @Xegara: The description also assumes that all the signals used in the expressions are in the `phy_clk` clock domain, since that is a condition for doing synchronous design, and else the required setup time is not ensured, as you point out.  If the other signals are not in the `phy_clk` domain, then I think you should take a general look at the design conditions, and determine if you can synchronize the signals to the `phy_clk`, since it will make design so much simpler.  You may want to google "vhdl asynchronous clock domains", or look at http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276114

Comment: So you mean that synchronizing everything with the phy_clk would result to a much simpler design. Does that also implies that the compensation must be done by other vhd modules such as the vhd module should assert the phy_start in the falling edge of the clock or prolonging it to two clock cycles?

Comment: @Xegara: It is much simpler to do design with one clock, and where all the other signals used in expressions are relative to that clock, so-called synchronous design.  Unless falling edge of clock is really needed, then stick with rising edge.  If the signal behavior allows, then synchronize `phy_start` to rising edge of `phy_clk` using doule-sync flip flops as described in EEtimes article, and then you can design based on synchronous design principles.  The double-sync should should be done at one place only, and output be used in all modules using `phy_start`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42869/discussion-between-mortenzdk-and-xegara)

Answer (score 0):

If `phy_start` is created synchronously by another process, then you have no problem.

Just read it in your other synchronous process, and compare against a value you stored from the last clock cycle, to detect when the signal has changed from `0` to `1`:

```
process (phy_clk)
  variable last_start : std_logic := '0';
begin
  if rising_edge(phy_clk) then
     if phy_start = '1' and last_start = '0' then
        -- do something in here
     end if;
     last_start := phy_start;
  end if;
end process;
```