# VHDL, Multiple reset counter

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, reset

I need a counter that can reset when reaching 800 or when theres a falling edge in an input, i get errors like, "unsupported Clock statement", or " cannot be synthesized bad synchronous description"

i tryied several things, i need something like this

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  if Counter >= 800 OR rising_edge(X) then
     Counter <= (others => '0');
  else
     Counter <= Counter + 1;
end if
```

X is the input signal that resets the counter, counter is a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

It says "bad synchronous" description, because you try to describe registers with multiple clock sources. There are some FPGA families that do support this, but that's rare and uncommon.

First off, you wrote "falling edge in an input" but then used "rising_edge(X)"...

Secondly, no way that counter is std_logic_vector with you doing comparisons to integer constants. I assume at least unsigned. Except if you use deprecated packages, of course -- which you shouldn't!

Thirdly, you failed to mention any relationship of X with clk.

A standard solution would be

```
counter_p : process (
    clk,
    reset
    )
begin

    if reset = '0' then

        counter <= 0;

    elsif rising_edge(clk) then

        counter <= counter + 1;

        if (counter = 800) then
            counter <= 0;
        end if;

    end if;

end process counter_p;
```

If X is synchronous, then implement a synchronous reset.

If you truly need asynchronous reset only on falling edge -- meaning not when reset is asserted, just on the clock after the asserting edge -- then you will have to resort to oversampling using clk and a shift register, test for falling edge and generate an (a)synchronous reset from that.

Comment: woa, im just a noob, thank you for your response, i admit that that i write that code without checking it, sorry. Also, i dont understand what do you mean by a synch reset, i just want the counter to reset with a falling/rising edge and to automatically reset it it goes to a number. and yes it is a vector im using ARITH and UNSIGNED libraries if i use reset = '0' counter wont get "counting" untill reset goes to '1' again, i want just to reset it when it falls/rises but to continue counting until 800 or until another falling/rising edge, Thank you.

Comment: Then you have to synchronize the reset signal yourself like the last part of my post said. However, you will have 1 clk cycle uncertainty with that approach.
But I strongly urge you to reconsider your design and use standard design methodology, i.e. asynchronous or synchronous resets.

Answer (score 0):

You can't act on the rising edge of any signal other than the clock.  You have to look at the previous value and the current value and decide if it's "rising". There seem to be quite a few of these sorts of questions this week!

For example:

- [change signal inside a process with if statement - VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460242/change-signal-inside-a-process-with-if-statement-vhdl/20472791#20472791)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473392/106092